# LINQ Join Group By Select New

Tags: linq, select, group-by

I have the following entities:

User is:

```
public String Id { get; set; }
public String FirstName { get; set; }
public String LastName { get; set; }
```

Assessment is:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int SymptomId { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

A User can have 0, 1 or more Assessments.

I have written the following LINQ:

```
// Get Paged Users Recent Assessment List:
var _usersWithRecentAssessment =
from U in _context.Users
join A in _context.Assessments on U.Id equals A.UserId
group A by A.UserId into uaGroup
select uaGroup.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

_usersWithRecentAssessment = _usersWithRecentAssessment.OrderByDescending(ua => ua.CreatedDate);
```

which returns the most recent symptom assessment for all Users that have completed an Assessment (and orders the assessment list in descending order of Assessment CreatedDate) as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1052,
        "symptomId": 44,
        "userId": "b978d113-7da7-4b7f-a121-9dd71e158dd4",
        "createdDate": "2019-11-16T12:50:05.2175621"
    },
    {
        "id": 1051,
        "symptomId": 44,
        "userId": "5230f4b7-bf2a-46b0-88a0-6f13fa5caa91",
        "createdDate": "2019-11-03T14:46:21.6598763"
    }
]
```

I would like to return the following AssessmentDTO

where AssessmentDTO is:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int SymptomId { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
public string UserLastName { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

which contains the additional attributes `UserId, UserFirstName, and UserLastName` from the User entity.

I have tried unsuccessfully to add 'select new AssessmentDTO() { }' at the end of the LINQ.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `Assessment` should have a navigation property `User` and it all becomes very simple.

Comment: Thanks Gert. Could you help me with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

A User has zero or more Assessments, every Assessment belongs to exactly one User. This is a standard one-to-many relation with a foreign key.

For your problem, you can use one of the overload of [Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8). First get all `Users with their assessments` and as a result keep only the most recent assessment:

```
var UsersWithMostRecentAssessment = dbContext.Users
    .GroupBy(dbContext.Assessments,              // GroupJoin Users and Assessments
    user => user.Id,                             // From every User take the Id
    assessment => assessment.UserId,             // From every Assessment take the UserId

    // ResultSelector: take each User with its zero or more Assessments to make one new:
    (user, assessmentsOfThisUser) => new
    {
        User = user,
        MostRecentAssessment = assessmentsOfThisUser
                               .OrderByDescending(assessment => assessment.CreatedDate)
                               .FirstOrDefault(),
                               // might be null if this User has not assessments at all
    })

    // Now get the User with its MostRecentAssessment (or null) to make one new:
    .Select(userAssessMent => new
    {
         // Values from the most recent assessment:
         Id = userAssessment.MostRecentAssessment.Id,
         SymptomId = userAssessment.MostRecentAssessment.SymptomId,
         ...

         // Values from the User:
         UserId = userAssessment.User.Id,
         FirstName = userAssessment.User.FirstName,
         LastName = userAssessment.User.LastName,
         ...
    })
```

Note: this will go wrong if there are users without assessments, because they won't have a most recent assessment. You can omit these users before the final Select:

```
.Where(userAssessment => userAssessment.MostRecentAssessment != null)
```

Or if you want these Users in your endresult:

```
 // Values from the most recent assessment or default if null
 Id = userAssessment.MostRecentAssessment.Id ?? 0,
 SymptomId = userAssessment.MostRecentAssessment.SymptomId ?? 0,
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have obviously got a lot to learn about LINQ.

I have included the .Where before the final .Select as follows:

.Where(userAssessment => userAssessment.MostRecentAssessment != null)

// Now get the User with its MostRecentAssessment (or null) to make one new:
.Select(userAssessment => new
{
...
}

However, I get the following exception at .GroupBy:

ArgumentNullException: Type arguments for queryable.groupby cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Apparently the error is in the GroupBy. In visual studio, hover your mouse above the arguments and check whether they are correct. I guess the problem is in the ResultSelector. Make a simple result selector and see if that solves the problem. Try to change the ResultSelector in small steps to the one that does what you want.